# Linear Isomorphism And Completeness

Tags: analysis

I am just a beginner. So please be patient with me.

> Consider $X=\{\frac 1 n : n \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{0\}$.
>   Prove that the  vector space of continuous functions on $X$ is linearly isomorphic to the space of convergent sequences in $\mathbb R$. Using this result, conclude that the set of
>   convergent sequences in the NLS of all  bounded real sequences under the sup norm is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\bf Hint:$ If $f: X\to\mathbb R$ is continuous then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\frac 1 n)=f(0)$ hence $f$ is a convergent sequence. On the other hand, if $(a_n)$ converges to $a$ then the function $f: X\to\mathbb R$ given by $\frac 1 n\to a_n$ and $0\to a$ it is easily seen to be a continuous function.